# Creating a GPO to deploy an msi using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, group-policy

Several issues I need help with as I'm a newb at creating Group Policy and at batch file scripting. We are deploying PrinterLogic client to all domain users, so I'm trying to do this with a group policy. To install, we have to deploy an msi package with some arguments which will configure the client with a HOME URL. And, naturally, I only want it to install once. If it's already installed, it should NOT run again. So in the GPO, I have under Computer Configuration>>Preferences to copy the installer.msi from a network file share to C:\Temp. Then in Computer Configuration>>Policies>>Windows Settings>>Startup, this is where I've placed my batch script. Rather than setting a Registry Key to Run Once (in case it fails for some reason), I'd prefer to have the batch script check first if the application already exists (IF EXIST) or does not exist (IF NOT EXIST), not sure which is the better way to go, and I want to make sure I have my syntax correct. Will this work?

```
@ECHO OFF
Printer Logic Client Installer
ECHO This script will install the Printer Logic client by deploying the 'C:\Temp\PrinterInstallerClient.msi' package
PAUSE

IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Printer Properties Pro\Printer Installer Client\PrinterInstallerClient.exe"

msiexec /I C:\Temp\PrinterInstallerClient.msi /passive HOMEURL=https://XXXXXXXX.printercloud.com AUTHORIZATION_CODE=XXXXXXXX" /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"
```

Comment: *Will this work?* Couldn't you test it yourself to find out?

Comment: `IF NOT EXIST "file"` is only half a statement, it should be `IF NOT EXIST "file" command`. If you want to complete your statement on the next line, you'll need to open a parenthesized block, 1. `IF NOT EXIST "file" (`, 2. `command)`. Almost all commands have built in help, `IF` is no different. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `IF /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its usage information.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't really be checking to see if the executable is installed in a specific location. As you're using the Microsoft Installer, you should be able to see if the program has been installed, using WMI. Alternatively, you could check for its uninstall information in the registry.